# Monitoring Clustered MSMQ

Tags: windows-server-2003, cluster

According to Microsoft, Systems Center Operations Manager cannot monitor clustered MSMQ's on Server 2003. The Microsoft rep referenced this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884975). and said it applied to our problem. So, my question is: what does the serverfault community recommend to monitor msmq's in a Server 2003 cluster?

What I am looking for is something to monitor the number of messages on the queues and send an alert if messages appear on the fault queue or if the messages back-up on the main queue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to monitor queue depth, I would break out your powershell handbook or buy your favorite developer a beer or two and look into the .NET System.Messaging namespace. You can run a scheduled task every few minutes and get near-realtime alerting that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MSMQ but if it supports STOMP (and as a message broker I guess it should) you can use Perl's [Net::Stomp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Stomp/) module to send and receive a test message. I've been using [following Nagios plugin](http://www.monitoringexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=Detailed=2856.html;d=1) to check ActiveMQ.

The point is that you can use whatever monitoring system you employ (whether it be Nagios or anything else) and check if your message broker works properly sending STOMP messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good resource:

MSMQ 4.0 Performance Counters and the NetNameForPerfCounters Registry Key
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2007/12/14/msmq-4-0-performance-counters-and-the-netnameforperfcounters-registry-key.aspx